# How to fix legacy and third-party systems that send emails to office365 users?

Tags: email, microsoft-office, office365, exchange, smtp

Esp. in the last couple of years, we have seen steadily increasing problems when our internal applications/servers send emails (reports, alerts, warnings, and what-not info) to our internal employees/users in office365 -- and microsoft has gradually "tightened" the spam-filter rules -- that many internal **legitimate** (but non-authorized smtp) emails get spam-classed (to junk-folder) but also **increasingly often get** **completely blocked** by the office365 "blackbox" spam-filters, and never get delivered.

Microsoft also disabled basic-auth last spring(2023) and, AFAIU, you now must use OAuth authentication to **ensure** server mails actually get delivered -- which is also anything but trivial to setup correctly in their cloud-solution...

But I'm **particularly wondering about all old/legacy systems, or systems once procured from third-parties, etc**, that virtually every company with in-house hosting run...?
And where it can be quite a daunting/"impossible" task to make them use OAuth authentication...

How do all companies on planet Earth generally handle this potentially very serious situation today, that internal server-emails just disappear (with any possible number of bad consequences)?

In my partly sys-admin role, I am surprised I hear so little about this in the it-business today.

Am I missing something entirely?

Or does everyone really just ignore this problem?

Comment: How do the servers send mail, exactly? Do they just directly contact O365 MX on port 25 and send from "root@websrv123.example.com", or do they send from authenticated mailbox (talking to O365 on port 587 and SMTP auth)?

Comment: @u1686_grawity --- Good question... I'm not involved in configuring the smtp-relays used by the RHEL-servers we generally use. 
But obviously, they are *not* doing OAuth towards office365, which is the root-cause, afaiu(?) -- Is it possible to just configure all smtp-relays to do OAuth towards office365?
And does that mean all mails then will seem to come from the same sender? 
Or how will that appear?

Comment: The standard answer for this problem almost always is: train the spamfilter. So you would contact the Microsoft365 admin, tell them what the date/time of the email message is, or even better, provide them with the messageid as found in the headers of the mail that you find in the junk folder, then in the security center, find the email, and train the spamfilter that this mail is valid. You can also do things like SPF and DKIM checks.

Comment: @LPChip --- what I understand, the spam-algorithms are some kind of "black box" controlled by microsoft... have seen sometimes, two almost identical messages, one of them gets delivered and the other gets blocked... nobody can explain why.... anyways, cannot be a managable solution when you have maybe hundreds of systems emailing various kinds of reports etc to different users...

Comment: What happens is that as each message is processed by the spamfilter, microsoft learns from it and adjusts its filter accordingly. It will probably have the status unsure with one and blocked with the other. If you train that message as approved, it almost always works.

Comment: umm... so some "office365 admin" is supposed to sit there and click "correct" or "wrong" for every message that was forwarded/junked/blocked by the filter? or how does that practically work?

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft also disabled basic-auth last spring(2023) and, AFAIU, you now must use OAuth authentication to ensure server mails actually get delivered

> But I'm particularly wondering about all old/legacy systems, or systems once procured from third-parties, etc

Microsoft has not blocked basic auth for SMTP yet, as there are many old devices that cannot use modern auth.

[image]

(Although if Azure Security defaults is enabled in your tenant, it would be blocked)

To use basic auth, you may need to check the four settings in this Microsoft documentation:
[Error: Authentication unsuccessful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-lob-applications-that-send-email-using-off#error-authentication-unsuccessful)

In short:

1. SMTP AUTH is enabled on the licensed mailbox
2. Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) is disabled on the licensed mailbox
3. Azure Security Defaults is disabled in your tenant
4. no conditional access policy assigned to this mailbox blocks legacy authentication